# Chrome SVG renders incorrectly at certain sizes

Tags: google-chrome, svg

**EDIT**: As commenter Kaiido pointed out, the issue is a bug with Chrome caused by a really small blur filter + zoom. Snippet below illustrates duplicate red lines, when there should only be one.

```css
svg { zoom: 0.67 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1e3" height="1e3" viewBox="0 0 265 265">
  <filter id="filter2865-5" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.005"/>
  </filter>
  <path d="M0,0 L265 265" stroke="red" filter="url(#filter2865-5)"/>
</svg>
```

---

I have reproduced this on a couple different devices, but I can only cause it in Chrome. Firefox doesn't seem to have this issue.

At certain zoom/resize levels my SVG has strange rendering artifacts, like [weird moved duplications of existing objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzrZF.jpg). [This does not happen at like 125% zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDJAR.jpg)

Here is the svg file: https://petsclub2.nfshost.com/img/oldruins_map.svg

If it helps, this image is created in Inkscape, and there are a lot of complex objects / paths...

Comment: When your example file is too complicated, e.g because it has "a lot of complex objects / paths", then try to simplify it as much as possible so that only what is really needed to reproduce the problem is there, what we call a [mcve]. I made it for you in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snf6meua/), that you can copy, but in this case, since this is a Chrome bug, it might be better to just [report it to them](https://crbug.com). Let them know that the really small blur filter + zoom triggers this rendering issue.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you! I was unable to isolate the issue from stepwise removing elements, so I will add an edit to my question that points to your fiddle and explanation, and report the bug as suggested.

Comment: You can even create a live example from your question directly rather than link to out-sources. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do